# How to display widget content in to other non-widget file in elgg

Tags: php, widget, elgg

```
I want to display widget content into non-widget view file.
    but that procedure i don't know.
    pls. help me, get me some extension or information about that.
    in Elgg.
```

will get code from liked_content Plugin file is **elgg.2.2.1\mod\liked_content\views\default\widgets\liked_con‌​tent\content.php**

and

paste this code in to

**elgg.2.2.1\mod\profile\views\default\profile\owner_block.php**

Some, Changes I have Do... Now

```
                 $widget = $vars['entity'];                            
                 $container = $widget->getContainerEntity();    // problem here                     
                 $options =eligo_get_display_entities_options($widget); // and, problem is here                          
                $options['annotation_names'] = array('likes');

                if (elgg_instanceof($container, 'user') && $widget->my_likes !== 0) {
                  $options['annotation_owner_guids'] = $container->guid;
                }

                if (!elgg_instanceof($container, 'user') && !elgg_instanceof($container, 'group')) {
                  unset($options['container_guids']);
                }


                if ($widget->eligo_sortby == 'mostliked') {
                  $dbprefix = elgg_get_config('dbprefix');
                  $likes_metastring = get_metastring_id('likes');
                  $options['selects'] = array("(SELECT count(distinct l.id) FROM {$dbprefix}annotations l WHERE l.name_id = $likes_metastring AND l.entity_guid = e.guid) AS likes");

                  $options['order_by'] = 'likes ASC';
                  if ($widget->eligo_sortby_dir == 'desc') {
                    $options['order_by'] = 'likes DESC';
                  }
                }

                $content = elgg_list_entities_from_annotations($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display it anywhere you would like with the help of function dynamic_sidebar() (i.e. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

```
dynamic_sidebar('your-widget-id');
```

Comment: But, In Elgg , I Have To Do THis

Comment: I Have Some Code ... That Dsiplay Above..

Comment: I Will uses 3 Plugins, **1.owner_followers_counter, 2.Liked_Content,3.au_widget,** I will get this code from **liked_content **and put into the **owner_block.php** so its not working

Answer (score 0):

In Elgg each widget is also a view. So you can use the line below

```
elgg_view('widgets\liked_con‌​tent\content');
```

But in this case you should take care to load the right your params

An alternative way is the following

```
echo elgg_view_layout('widgets', array (
'title' => 'Give a title',
'content' => elgg_view ( 'widgets/mycustomwidget/content' ),
'show_add_widgets' => false,
));
```

The "mycustomwidget" is name of the widget we want to display it's content.

Comment: An alternative way is the following